# Issue with CPLEX constraint

Tags: c++14, cplex

I am building a CPLEX model (VRP-like). In one of the model constraints I am forcing an initial flow from the depot to the each one of the different sets of customers I have, at least, sufficient to cope with the demands of the customers of the sets.

As such, say I have `n` different `I[i]` sets, with `i = 1..n`. And then, for each `I[i]` the sum of the arcs leaving the depot to each one of the elements in `I[i]` shall count as the capacity of a truck, say `Q`, if the arc is traversed. Hence, the aforementioned sum shall be greater or equal to the sum of the demands, say `d[I[i][j]]` for each one of the customers `j` in `I[i]` to ensure enough trucks will enter the set `I[i]`.

In other "words": `\sum_{j\in I_i} {Q*x_{0, j}}\geq\sum_j\in I_i{d_j}`. If I export the CPLEX model I have those constraints, e.g.

```
V.1.FlowCreation_a(1)#1484:     600000 ArcRouting(2)(1)(1)(44)#17223
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(1)(1)(45)#17225
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(2)(1)(44)#17229
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(2)(1)(45)#17231
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(3)(1)(44)#17235
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(3)(1)(45)#17237
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(4)(1)(44)#17241
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(4)(1)(45)#17243
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(5)(1)(44)#17247
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(5)(1)(45)#17249
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(6)(1)(44)#17253
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(6)(1)(45)#17255
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(7)(1)(44)#17259
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(7)(1)(45)#17261
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(8)(1)(44)#17265
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(8)(1)(45)#17267
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(9)(1)(44)#17271
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(9)(1)(45)#17273
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(10)(1)(44)#17277
                              + 600000 ArcRouting(2)(10)(1)(45)#17279
                              >= 12000
```

The first dimension on the `ArcRouting(..)(..)(..)(..)` variables describes the number of the set of elements, 2 in that case, the second one the vehicle number, ranging from 1 to 10, while the third describes the departure node, and the fourth one the arrival node. That is why the third one is always 1, since node 0 is renamed as 1 during the LP exportation, and the fourth one only contains 44 and 45 since that specific set only contains a couple of elements.

As you can notice, it suffices that an arc be set to one (regardless of the vehicle used or customer from `I[2]` to visit) to meet the constraint, since, one truck could deliver up to 600.000 units while customers' joint demand is only 12.000 units.

The problem is that when I try to solve the model with the `mod.solve()` I get the following error:

```
Warning: Control callbacks may disable some MIP features.
Lazy constraint(s) or lazy constraint callback is present.
    Disabling dual reductions (CPX_PARAM_REDUCE) in presolve.
    Disabling non-linear reductions (CPX_PARAM_PRELINEAR) in presolve.
Infeasibility row 'V.1.FlowCreation_a[1]':  0 >= 12000.
Presolve time = 0.08 sec. (20.62 ticks)

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.09 sec. (21.15 ticks)
Sequential b&c:
  Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
                          ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.09 sec. (21.15 ticks)
```

What is the `Infeasibility row 'V.1.FlowCreation_a[1]':  0 >= 12000.` letting me know of my model that I don't fully understand?

Comment: I have already checked in my model to make sure the `ArcRouting(..)(..)(..)(..)` variables' bounds have not been set to zero, which could clearly lead to an infeasible row... What else can it be?

Comment: Could it be that you're missing a call to [IloCplex.extract](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloAlgorithm.html?view=kc#method_extract) after making some changes to the model?

Comment: Nope, I am not modifying the model anywhere. I am only declaring it, and solving it... Apparently CPLEX has identified that a linear combination of a set of my model constraints implies that my LHS is taking value zero. I will dig into it and explain the problem to serve as reference to others...